# Shell script, split string into everything before and after the last whitespace character

Tags: regex, string, awk, whitespace, solaris

I'm having some issues with separating a string in a shell script. I've been trying similar bits of code I've found online for RegEx, perl, awk, grep etc... but I can't seem to get the required result.

Basically I have a number of strings. Most are in the following format:
long string, space, number e.g.

```
Something!Something_Something_@Something_Something 10
```

However a small number aren't all the one string (they should be!) but they have spaces instead of underscores, e.g.

```
Something!Something_Something_@Something Something 10
```

or

```
Something!Something - Something_@Something Something 10
```

Each string is then formatted as follows:

```
... |awk '{printf "%-100s %10d\n", $1, $2}' > file.out
```

which prints the correct result for the strings which contain no spaces

```
Something!Something_Something_@Something_Something                  10
```

However in the case of the first example it only prints the following due to the space delimiter:

```
Something!Something_Something_@Something                        10
```

So basically I need a way to pull out everything before the last " " space and assign it to $1 in the awk printf statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

It's a Solaris 5.10 server by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hackjob but this will work

```
awk '{x=$NF;NF--;printf "%-100s %10d\n", $0, x}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jidder. While your answer does pull all the string out whether separated by whitespace or not it also list the numerical value twice:                                                      
Something!Something_Something_@Something Something 10        10          

I need it to display like this:           Something!Something_Something_@Something Something         10            

Also I understand that $NF is the last space delimited field in a line, but could you explain what "NF--;" does. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't print two 10ss ?. NF-- removes the final field. You would get two 10s if you left this out.

Comment: Sorry Jidder, not sure what's going on. I have cut down my program to just one line to test this, but it is still printing the number twice (i.e. the whole error and number, then a space and a number again). Here is the whole line (apologies, it's not going to win any awards for brevity!!): 

/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E [_@*] filein.log |/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E -i [ERR]|sort|/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -v '/'|awk '{x=$NF;NF--;printf "%-100s %10d\n", $0, x}' > fileout.out

Comment: can you give an example of What exactly is in a string ? What version of awk are you using, and are you sure that the ouput from your command is what you expect ?

Comment: OK, here is an example of a couple of the input strings:

BusinessApp!IFT_LIVE36001_@DTI - Import Notification Output Queue 0
CAP!IFT_LIVE38001_@queueerror 1658

I wasn't able to find out which awk version is on the server. I tried the usual ways: -v, --version, what, etc... Both oawk and nawk are in usr/bin however.

I have tried running your command with nawk instead of awk but the result is the same. 

Yes, the result of my grep statements is in the format of the two sample strings I have supplied above in this comment.

Comment: So I've tried your command on another machine and you are correct, it does work as you have stated. I'm not sure why it is not working on the Solaris server but I guess I will have to come up with a plan B to tackle this. Thanks for your help!